# Left property does not change with transition

Tags: javascript

CSS:

```
.elementToTransit {
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: left 2s linear;
}
```

JS (when page is first loaded transition left becomes 30%, but when the arrow button is clicked for some reason left property won't change (if transition is turned on):

```
applyTransition(arrowClicked = false) {
  const element =  document.querySelector(".elementToTransit");
  if(arrowClicked === false){
    element.style.left = '30%'
  } else {
    element.style.left = '50%'
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: How are you calling the function? Can you post enough of your code (relevant HTML, CSS and JavaScript) to allow us to reproduce the issue you describe?

Comment: Side note: That update of the `left` property can be more concisely (and to my mind, more clearly) written like this: `element.style.left = arrowClicked ? "50%" : "30%";` In comparisons, you never need `=== false` or `=== true`, you *already* have a boolean, just use it directly.